# matplotlib legend performance issue

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, legend

I am using Jupyter-notebook with python 3.6.2 and matplotlib to plot some data.

When I plot my data, I want to add a legend to the plot (basically to know which line is which)

However calling `plt.legend` takes a lot of time (almost as much as the plot itself, which to my understanding should just be instant).

Minimal toy problem that reproduces the issue:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Toy useless data (one milion x 4)
my_data = np.random.rand(1000000,4)

plt.plot(my_data)
#plt.legend(['A','C','G','T'])
plt.show()
```

The data here is just random and useless, but it reproduces my problem:
If I uncomment the `plt.legend` line, the run takes almost double the time

Why? Shouldn't the legend just look at the plot, see that 4 plots have been made, and draw a box assigning each color to the corresponding string?

Why is a simple legend taking so much time?

Am I missing something?

Comment: By default, the legend will be placed in the "best" location, which requires computing how many points from each line are inside a potential legend box. If there are many points, this can take a while. Drawing is much faster when specifying a location other than "best".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Replicating the answer by @bnaecker, such that this question is answered:*

By default, the legend will be placed in the "best" location, which requires computing how many points from each line are inside a potential legend box. If there are many points, this can take a while. Drawing is much faster when specifying a location other than "best", e.g. `plt.legend(loc=3)`.